# Amanda backup software using postfix generates invalid sendmail option '-s'

Tags: backup, sendmail

I recently updated postfix on my CentOS 6 server to support a new email relay, and everything is working except my Amanda backup software, which is no longer sending status emails.  When I run "amreport" on the command line, it gives me these errors:

```
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
sendmail: invalid option -- 's'
sendmail: fatal: usage: sendmail [options]
amreport: mail command exited with status 75
```

However, in my amanda.conf file, I have this

```
mailer "/usr/sbin/sendmail -t"
```

Where is Amanda and/or postfix getting the "s" option?  Does anyone know how to fix this?  Thanks in advance to all who respond.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by replacing `/usr/sbin/sendmail -t` with `/bin/mailx`.  For more information (and with due credit to "HBruijn"), see the following link: [https://serverfault.com/questions/1147855/amanda-backup-software-using-postfix-generates-invalid-sendmail-option-s](https://I%20resolved%20the%20issue%20by%20replacing%20%22/usr/sbin/sendmail%20-t%22%20with%20%22/bin/mailx%22.%20%20For%20more%20information,%20see%20the%20following%20link:%20https://serverfault.com/questions/1147855/amanda-backup-software-using-postfix-generates-invalid-sendmail-option-s)